# Como traer un nombre a traves de del id?

Tags: laravel

Buenas estoy realizando un proyecto en laravel, donde tengo la tabla customers con sus respectivos campos. Esta misma tabla contiene jerarquia ya que un cliente puede tener un cliente padre como no.
Por eso mismo mi tabla esta definida de esta manera:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('company')->nullable();
            $table->string('legal_entity')->nullable();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('cuit');
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->integer('id_parentCompany');
            
            
        });
    }
```

una vista que se llama view-customer.blade.php:

donde muestro los clientes que tengo cargados:

```
<tr>
                            <th style="display:none ">Codigo</th>
                            
                            <th>Empresa</th>                                
                            <th>Email</th>                                
                            <th>Cuit</th>
                            <th>Razon Social</th>
                            <th>Holding</th>

                        </tr>
```

Y luego quiero mostrar los datos con un foreach:

```
@foreach($allData as $key => $customer)
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display: none;">{{$key+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->company }}</td>
                            
                            <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->cuit}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->legal_entity}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm bg-gradient-yellow"  href="{{ route('customers.detail', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);" href="{{ route('customers.edit', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('customers.delete', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                    class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Como puedo hacer yo para que cuando pida el id_parentCompany poder obtener el nombre de la empresa relacionado a ese id.

No se si me explique bien pero les dejo un ejemplo

Si yo tengo a disney como empresa con id =1, y su id_parentCompany = 0 ya que no pertenece a otra compañía. Luego tengo a espn como empresa con id = 2 y su id_parentCompany es = 1 ya que tiene a disney como compañía padre.

Comment: Suena a que **tal vez** un join a la misma tabla te sirva, ¿puedes editar y mostrar que has intentado al respecto, es decir tu query?

Comment: Sisi se que se necesita hacer un inner join donde en la tabla customers me devuelva una nueva columna que se llame parent company donde el id = id_parentCompany, pero lo que nose es como pasar esos datos a la vista en laravel @BetaM

Comment: ¿Pasarlos o iterarlos?, por que son cosas distintas, si es para enviarlos entoncces un array asociativo donde el valor sea la query dentro del método view (como segundo argumento) lo resuelve, ahora pintar esos datos ya es otra cosa

Comment: pasarlos creo es decir si yo quiero el nombre de la empresa que se encuentra en la tabla de customers directamente haria esto, <td>{{$customer->company }}</td>, pero si yo quiero obtener el holding es decir el parent company tendria que hacer un inner join de esta manera "SELECT p.nombre as Holding,
c.nombre as EmpresaChild
FROM clientes as p INNER JOIN clientes as c ON p.id_cliente = c.id_clientePadre", Como hago yo para que cuando haga "<td>{{$customer->id_parentCompany}}</td>" el framework entienda que lo que yo quiero que me devuelva es el resultado de esta consulta. @BetaM

Answer (score 1):

En tu modelo **App\Customer.php** deberías de tener dos relaciones.

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'id_parentCompany', 'id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer', 'id', 'id_parentCompany');
}
```

Y después en la plantilla donde pones

```
<td>{{$customer->legal_entity}}</td>
```

sustitúyelo por:

```
<td>{{$customer->parent->legal_entity}}</td>
```

Comment: MateoG98 has abierto otra pregunta que es continuación de esta, te contesto aquí. Si tu modelo es **App\Customer** tienes que poner **App\Customer**, si es **App\Model\Customer** pues **App\Model\Customer**, deberías de intentar entender las cosas, no hacer un _copy and paste_